# How many ways are there to pick r objects from n objects when each object appears an odd number of times

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, computer-science

I had misunderstood this problem earlier, and wanted to try again in the correct way, and I think I've got the correct start but I'm not sure how to progress.

So from reading my notes here's what I came up with if i want to pick r objects from n objects but only when each object appears an odd number of times, then for each object I would have the following

object is picked once x

object is picked thrice $x^{3}$

object is picked five times $x^{5}$

and so on... so I think you would get

$(x+x^{3}+x^{5}... +x^r)$

now if this is how many ways I can pick it for one object for n I think I can do

$(x+x^{3}+x^{5}... +x^r)^{n}$

Now I'm not sure where to go from here, or if I've done it correctly up until this point.

Yes this is a duplicate post but the original was completely wrong, thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Using combination:-
C(n,1)+C(n,3)+C(n,5)+..... = 2^(n-1)

Comment: Can you explain the math behind that a bit more please?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It's a little unclear how you responses answers the question. Consider adding some further explanation on why your answer solves the OP's problem. In addition, please use MathJax to format your future posts. In addition, [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. In this case, binomial coefficients can be typeset using `{}_nC_r` or `{n \choose r }` which produce ${}_nC_r$ and ${n \choose r }$ respectively.